# In this implementation of stack using linked list in C++, accessing struct headNode members count and top is giving run time error

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Im having trouble in implementing a Stack using linked list. In this implementation of stack using linked list in c++, struct headNode part count and top is not accessible in method createNode and push and giving run time error. Please tell me why struct headNode->top and headNode->count  is not accessible or if you find any other error in this code.

```
 struct Node{
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int data):data(data), next(NULL){}
    };
    struct headNode{
    int count{0};
    Node *top ;
    headNode():top(NULL){}
    };
    class Stack{
    private:
        headNode *head;
        int c{0};
    public:
        Stack();
        void createStack(int data);
        void push(int data);
    };
        Stack::Stack():head(NULL){}
        void Stack:: createStack(int data)
        {
            Node *topNode= new Node(data);
            head->top=topNode; //RUNTIME ERROR IN THIS LINE OF CODE
            head->count=c++; //RUNTIME ERROR IN THIS LINE OF CODE
        }
        void Stack:: push(int data)
        {
            if(head==NULL)
            {
              createStack(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Node *topNode= new Node(data);
                topNode->next=head->top;
                head->top=topNode;
                head->count=c++;
            }

        }
    int main()
    {
        Stack s ;
        s.push(1);

    }
```

Comment: `head` was initialized to `NULL` and never assigned anything else. `head->top` tries to access the `top` member of a `head` hat does not exists, and that's the end of the program. I suspect you want to assign the newly created node directly to `head`.

Comment: You need to assign `head` to something other than `NULL` in `createSTack`. Just do `head = new headNode;`

Comment: Thank you all, error get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Stack s;` the constructor executes, but this line: `Stack::Stack():head(NULL)` initializes `head = NULL`, and then in the line `s.push(1);` the function `push` calls `createStack` (because the condition `head == NULL` is true), which in turn does:

```
head->top=topNode;
head->count=c++;
```

But `head` is still `NULL`, and produces the run-time error you experience.